# Show that if a bounded set $S$ is rectifiable, then so is the set $\overline{S}$, and $v(S)=v(\overline{S})$ Analysis on Manifolds by James R. Munkres

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification

I am reading "Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres.

The following problem is Exercise 7(a) on p.121 in this book.

> Exercise 7. Let $S$ be a bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
> (a) Show that if $S$ is rectifiable, then so is the set $\overline{S}$, and $v(S)=v(\overline{S})$.

I solved Exercise 7(a), but I am not sure my solution is ok or not.

I used the following facts:

> Fact 1:
> Let $S$ be a set in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
> Then, $\operatorname{Bd}(\overline{S})\subset\operatorname{Bd}S$.

> Fact 2:
> Let $S$ be a set in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
> Then, $\overline{S}-S=\operatorname{Bd}S-S$.

> Theorem 14.1 on p.112:
> A subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is rectifiable if and only if $S$ is bounded and $\operatorname{Bd}S$ has measure zero.

> Theorem 14.2(d) on p.112:
> Suppose $S$ is rectifiable. Then $v(S)=0$ if and only if $S$ has measure zero.

> Exercise 2 on p.120:
> Show that if $S_1$ and $S_2$ are rectifiable, so is $S_1-S_2$, and $$v(S_1-S_2)=v(S_1)-v(S_1\cap S_2).$$

Is my solution ok?

My solution is here:

> $S$ is rectifiable.
> So, by Thorem 14.1, $\operatorname{Bd}S$ has measure zero.
> By Fact 1, $\operatorname{Bd}(\overline{S})$ has measure zero.
> So, $\overline{S}$ is rectifiable by Theorem 14.1.
> So, by Exercise 2 on p.120, $\overline{S}-S$ is rectifiable and $v(\overline{S}-S)=v(\overline{S})-v(\overline{S}\cap S)=v(\overline{S})-v(S)$.
> By Fact 2, $\overline{S}-S=\operatorname{Bd}S-S\subset\operatorname{Bd}S$.
> Since $\operatorname{Bd}S$ has measure zero, $\overline{S}-S$ also has measure zero.
> By Theorem 14.2(d), $v(\overline{S}-S)=0$.
> So, $v(\overline{S})=v(S)$.